# Find min and max for multiple value in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have event "add_road" in my bigquery table with int value in distance and time parameters. I want to find max and min of param "distance" and "time".  I have tried this query, but it doesn't work as I want.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(param.value.double_value)
  FROM UNNEST (event.params) AS param
  WHERE param.key = "distance") AS distance,
  (SELECT MAX(param.value.int_value)
  FROM UNNEST (event.params) AS param
  WHERE param.key = "time") AS time
FROM 
  `ukrbikeapp.info_androidhive_firebase_ANDROID.app_events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) as event
WHERE event.name = "add_road"
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '201_05__')
```

I have no idea how to make this query. Please, give me some advice.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MAX(IF(param.key = "distance", param.value.double_value, NULL)) AS distance,
  MAX(IF(param.key = "time", param.value.int_value, NULL)) AS time
FROM data, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event, UNNEST(event.params) AS param
WHERE event.name = "add_road"
AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '201_05__')
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to move the computation of `MAX` to the outer select list instead so that you can find the maximums across all rows, not just within the arrays. For example,

```
SELECT
  MAX((SELECT param.value.double_value
  FROM UNNEST (event.params) AS param
  WHERE param.key = "distance")) AS distance,
  MAX((SELECT param.value.int_value
  FROM UNNEST (event.params) AS param
  WHERE param.key = "time")) AS time
FROM 
  `ukrbikeapp.info_androidhive_firebase_ANDROID.app_events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) as event
WHERE event.name = "add_road"
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '201_05__')
```